# How to insert custom redirect script in index.php without losing it on update

Tags: 8, redirection

At the moment I'm migrating an old site to Drupal. To redirect all old url's to new ones, I made a script that has to be inserted before anything goes off, so in index.php at the top.

```
   <?php

    include 'custom.php';

    use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    etc.etc.
```

All is fine until an update wipes this out.
Could (should?) it be done some other way to preserve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run code before the Drupal kernel is started use a middleware.

Use the drush code generator `drush gen middleware` and put your code in handle() of the generated middleware class:

*MymoduleMiddleware.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule;

use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

/**
 * MymoduleMiddleware middleware.
 */
class MymoduleMiddleware implements HttpKernelInterface {

  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * The kernel.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface
   */
  protected $httpKernel;

  /**
   * Constructs the MymoduleMiddleware object.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface $http_kernel
   *   The decorated kernel.
   */
  public function __construct(HttpKernelInterface $http_kernel) {
    $this->httpKernel = $http_kernel;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function handle(Request $request, $type = self::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = TRUE) {

    if ($request->getClientIp() == '127.0.0.10') {
      return new Response($this->t('Bye!'), 403);
    }

    return $this->httpKernel->handle($request, $type, $catch);
  }

}
```